# Rails:scope from parents of parents of parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a relation below

```
    School
    has_many :students
    has_many :accounts, :through => :students

    Student
    belongs_to :school
    has_one :account

    Account
    belongs_to :student
```

This is question, I've got couple of schools
and I want to get accounts belongs specific school with pagination
How can I load this?

```
    @accounts = Accounts.where(...).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

I missed my question
I've got a relation below

```
    School
    has_many :classrooms

    Classroom
    belongs_to :school
    has_many :students
    has_many :accounts, :through => :students

    Student
    belongs_to :classroom
    has_one :account

    Account
    belongs_to :student
```

and question is same :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to fit the update to your question

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do:

```
school = School.first
@accounts = school.accounts.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

**UPDATE**
Based on the updated question, you can still do and achieve the same result by using the query above:

```
School
  has_many :classrooms
  has_many :accounts, through: :classrooms
```

Answer (score 0):

you should find the school by id whatever school you want

```
@school = School.find(params[:id])
```

and you can get accounts associated with that particular school by this statement

```
@accounts = @school.accounts.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```